# php not working after apache directory change

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd, http-status-code-403

I have a dev box running and i changed the path of the vhost from /home/username/www to /home/username/public_html.

Retarted apache and now the site is giving me a 403 when i visit the site and php isnt working now either.

The server is centos 5.5 x64, php is 5.3.5

Any help is appriciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Paste your complete VirtualHost here.

Comment: @peter: https://gist.github.com/8dace001c0388b6caf6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am referring the portions between "

> `<VirtualHost 10.0.2.8:80>`

and

> `</VirtualHost>`

Document root and "Directory" directive are different.

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html
<Directory /home/mobile/www>
```

Make that same.

Also make sure that there is at least one file in DocumentRoot with any of the following name

```
index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
```

Answer (score 0):

Check acccess permission to this folder and to parent folder. Drfault permission to user's homedir in CentOS is 700 (rwx for owner, no access to any other user).

Comment: @Paul: I did chmod 0777 /home/username/, no luck

Comment: @Kyle Hudson: *ouch*, please do not do that unless you do not care about the safety of your server and others. 777 means that anyone can read and write to it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: It was only a temp measure to ensure it wasn't a simple permissions error. I will restore the permissions when this issue is resolved. Thanks for the concern :)

Comment: @Kyle Hudson: You said you've chmodded /home/username to 777. That's not recursive, have you tried `chmod +rx /home/username/public_html`?

Comment: @lekensteyn: No change

Comment: @Kyle Hudson: what does your Apache error logs say?

Comment: @Lekensteryn: https://gist.github.com/896565

Comment: @Kyle - check both error and acces logs. Next check if SELinux enabled (in /etc/selinux/config)

Comment: @Paul: access log: https://gist.github.com/896576, error_log: https://gist.github.com/896565. SELinux is disabled.